Finding this Manwha I've been looking for
The Manwha is basically the fl gets reincarnated after her father and brothers abuse her and she dies. So the second life she doesn't trust them and doesn't bother with trying to win them over. I remember one scene where her and her brother was being chased and she fell of the cliff and her brother goes to try and catch her but she ends up pulling her hand back because she remembered when he called her dirty before. If anyone knows the name I would be forever grateful.

Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. When exactly did you watch this?

Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?
